# Why can't I extend my desktop 12.04 in KDE?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, kde

My display settings has no options to not mirror my screens. There is just no option for not mirroring my screens. The options are:

- turn on
- resolution
- refresh rate

I looked around for some graphic card or screen specific options and found none. I want to set up dual monitor. I am using Kubuntu 12.04 64-bit with NVidia GeForce GT 540M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this link and see if it solves your problem:

```
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/08/ubuntu-tips-how-to-setup-dual-monitor/
```

If that does not work check this post:

```
http://askubuntu.com/questions/303369/13-04-dual-monitors-on-my-desktop
```